# How can I stop the bookmark/reading list from showing up when I hover to the left of the screen in Safari?

Tags: safari

The bookmark/reading list sidebar shows up when one points their curosor to the left edge of the safari screen. Is there a setting that can prevent the sidebar from showing up?

Answer (score 1):

It only does that in fullscreen. I don't know of any switch for it.

Personally, I'd just never run it in fullscreen.